# Enabling/disabling form fields across multiple table rows with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm creating a 50 row table and in each row I want one form field to be enabled/disabled based on the option value of a dropdown box in that same tablerow.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
<tr id="tr1">
<td>
    <select id="tableDropDown" style="min-width: 100px;">
        <option>The Manufacturer</option>
        <option>Me</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input id="packSize" type="number" disabled></input></td>
</tr>

<tr id="tr2">
<td>
    <select id="tableDropDown" style="min-width: 100px;">
        <option>The Manufacturer</option>
        <option>Me</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input id="packSize" type="number" disabled></input></td>
</tr>
```

The jquery function I'm trying to use to accomplish this works fine on the first row, but does not change anything on other rows.  The input field "packSize" just stays disabled.

This is what it looks like:

```
$("#tableDropDown").on('change', function(){
            if ($(this).val() === "Me") {
                $("#packSize").removeAttr('disabled');
            }

            else {
                $("#packSize").attr({'disabled': 'disabled'});
            }
});
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The option doesn't have values in it.

Try this..

```
    <tr id="tr1">
<td><select id="tableDropDown" style="min-width: 100px;"><option value="other">The Manufacturer</option><option value="Me">Me</option></select></td>
<td><input id="packSize" type="number" disabled></input></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr2">
<td><select id="tableDropDown" style="min-width: 100px;"><option value="other">The Manufacturer</option><option value="Me">Me</option></select></td>
<td><input id="packSize" type="number" disabled></input></td>
</tr>
```

And can't have same id's for different elements

Comment: I just made the change you suggested and now it doesn't work for either row.  Is there some change I then need to make to my function in order for it to work?  Also, having different id's for every element seems cumbersome.  Is there some way to construct the function to avoid having to do this?

Comment: if you dont have any other select boxes then  use this `$(select).on('change', function(){
            if ($(this).val() === "Me") {
                $("#packSize").removeAttr('disabled');
            }

            else {
                $("#packSize").attr({'disabled': 'disabled'});
            }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ID selector in your case because ID is UNIQUE and for javascript in page can be only ONE occurrence. 
 (not recommend duplicity id's anytime, use class or other selector rather than id)

**html**

```
<table id="table">
<tr id="tr1">
<td>
    <select style="min-width: 100px;">
        <option>Me</option>
        <option>Manufacturer</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input type="number"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr id="tr2">
<td>
    <select style="min-width: 100px;">
        <option>Me</option>
        <option>Manufacturer</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input type="number"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**js**

```
$("#table").on('change', 'select', function(){
//    if($(this).val() == 'Manufacturer') { // by specific value or text
      if($(this)[0].selectedIndex != '0') { // by known index in option
        var el = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input'); // get input
            el.val(''); // reset value
            el.attr({'disabled': 'disabled'}); // set property
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td input').removeAttr('disabled'); // remove property
    }
});
```

working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73zjdkqt/)

## UPDATE

whats problem? Only change the if condition what you need.
I updated html and script above.

```
if($(this).val() == 'Manufacturer') { // by specific value or text
if($(this)[0].selectedIndex != '0') { // by known index in option
```

updated working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18ppm85v/)

Comment: Looking at the jsfiddle, it always enables when an option is chosen.  I only want it to disable if "manufacturer" is chosen, but not if "me" is chosen.